# Find Keywords and Data in pdf using python

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I am trying to find data in a financial statement. Basically I want to find accounts payable and take their associated values.

- Ex: Accounts Payable 219,200    290,000   .
- The first would represent year 2021 and the second 2022.

However I can't seem to get it to work.
[image]

I tried printing the lines to see if the keyword didn't exist and tried getting rid of the $ signs just in case that messed it up. But Im still stuck.

[This is my Code;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SRjH.png)

```
import PyPDF2
import re
# Path: "C:\Users\thavo\Downloads\ECCREPORT.pdf"
# "C:\Users\thavo\Downloads\FY23_Q1_Consolidated_Financial_Statements.pdf"




with open(r"C:\Users\thavo\Downloads\FY23_01_Consolidated_Financial_Statements.pdf", "rb") as file:
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
    page = pdf reader.pages[0]
    content_of_file = page.extract_text()
    lines_of_desired_page = content_of_file.split("\n")
    print (lines_of_desired_page)
    for line in lines_of_desired_page:
        if "net" in line.lower():
            financial_data = line.strip().split(" ")#[-2:]
            values = [re.sub(',', '', value) for value in financial_data]
            print (values[1])
        else:
            print ("Cant find") 
            break
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.apple.com/newsroom/pdfs/FY23_Q1_Consolidated_Financial_Statements.pdf

You need to first check such data is extractable before attempt to extract a target.

Using any PDFgrep or similar such as "read aloud" in a browser we can verify if there is a chance of recovery

```
pdftotext -layout FY23_Q1_Consolidated_Financial_Statements.pdf -|find "Accounts payable"


     Accounts payable                                                                          !        57,918     !      64,115
         Accounts payable                                                                  (6,075)          19,813
```

However I cannot see that first figure you give as a sample anywhere in that report!

What this indicates is that if you wish to extract 219,000 then it is in no way related to those characters in this document, so will need heavier interrogation.

Perhaps it's the total of 4 quarterly reports thus need selection and summation, easily done by saving the 2 x 4 values then adding the 2 sets of 4, and reversing the 2 years outputs into 2021 + 2022.  Also note for this quarter the greater one was 2021 not 2022, i.e. downwards so opposite to your up-beat indicator, but looking at gross is more indicative:

```
12 Month Gross Margin 
September 2021= $ 152,836,000,000
September 2022= $ 170,782,000,000
```

Here are the results for anything associated to net in this quarter, where biggest figures are

```
                                                              Three Months Ended
                                                          December 31,    December 25,
                                                             2022             2021
Total net sales                                     !      117,154       !     123,945
```

[image]